# Can OpenTok send an encryption key to Amazon S3 now that S3 supports server-side encryption with a user-supplied key?

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, opentok, tokbox

Currently, Tokbox's OpenTok supports archiving to Amazon S3. Amazon S3 supports AES-256 encryption at no additional charge. They recently added the ability to submit a user-generated key to encrypt the files with, but the key must come with the PUT request when adding the file to their service. Can I submit an encryption key to Tokbox/OpenTok to provide to Amazon S3 when archiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokbox now offers encrypted archiving as a Premium or Enterprise feature:

https://tokbox.com/blog/introducing-encrypted-archiving/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, OpenTok archiving doesn't currently accept an encryption key.

Comment: They should add this feature!

Comment: I realize this is way too late to be useful ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ but for posterity's sake, but we now offer encrypted archiving as a Premium or Enterprise feature: https://tokbox.com/blog/introducing-encrypted-archiving/